# GAM model for proportion data

Tags: r, proportion, generalized-additive-model

I'm trying to model number of devices failed out of total produced using GAM. I want the value to be bound between zero and one. Couldn't find anything that can solve this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

(I have number of failures, total produced and the factors driving failure for each batch produced)

I tried, Failure rate ~ s(factor1)+s(factor2)+s(factor3)
But there is no condition mentioning 'Failure rate' should be bound between 0 and 1.

Comment: Do some reading about generalized models and look at the `family` parameter of the `gam` function.

Comment: I have tried family=binomial and used failures as dependent variable with total items produced as weight. My predicted values are skewed towards 1 but my actuals are always skewed towards zero. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?